# Fire Event after Page Close or Redirected to other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have some problems with ASP.NET page cycle. I want to fire event when page is going to be closed or redirected to other page. I try to use `Page_Unload()` but it is going to be fire when page display and in any button click event it is firing `Page_Unload()`. I want only to fire event when page is going to be redirected or close. Then I have tried to use the Javascript function `window.onunload()`. Again, same problem: it is firing when the first page displays. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Hi, have a look at the window.onbeforeunload() function : window.onunload : http://forums.asp.net/t/1659364.aspx/1?window+uload+event+not+fired   or  http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/825556-using-onbeforeunload-javascript-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into Jquery's .beforeunload property.  Here is an example:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ return 'Click OK to exit'; });
```

Please note, beforeunload canot prevent a page from unloading or redirect it to another page for obvious reasons; it would be too easy to abuse.  Also if you just want to run a function before unloading, try the following:

```
$(window).unload(function(){ alert('Bye.'); });
```

Finally, don't forget to referrence jQuery in your head tag by using:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The above gets you the latest version from the internet and saves you the trouble to download it, and of course you can do so optionally, but I am just trying to get your thing to work asap.
Oh, I also found an example for you. [Click here](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-stop-page-from-exit.html) to see a page that calls a function before it closes.  Hope this helps bud.